# Error with deploy on $push method

Tags: meteor

I am developing on Windows and everything is OK. When I deploy to meteor.com I get a

```
MongoError: $each term takes only $slice (and optionally $sort) as complements [409]
```

Error in relations to this method.

```
setFave: function(recordId, userId){
    Records.update(recordId, { $push: { favouritedBy: userId }});
},
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, I did

```
Records.update({_id:recordId}, { $push: { favouritedBy: userId }});
```

if you are using mongo ObjectId then you need to make sure the recordId is a mongo Id

this is how to make an objectId

```
objectId = function(strId){
  if(typeof(strId)=="undefined") strId=null;
  return new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(strId)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Kitten.update({name: 'fluffy'}, {$push: {values: {$each: [2,3]}}}, {upsert:true}, function(err){
    if(err){
            console.log(err);
    }else{
            console.log("Successfully added");
    }
```

});

Comment: Code-only answers are often frowned upon, especially if no comments or text is there to explain it. This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.